# How to show default value in group by?

Tags: sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT DATE,COUNT(DATE) FROM TABLE WHERE DATE BETWEEN DATE1 AND DATE2 GROUP BY DATE..
```

Result will be like(for date 1/2/2012 to 3/2/2012 i.e 3 dates)

```
1/2/2012  5
2/2/2012  6
3/2/2012  9
```

Sometimes if the count is  Null means it does not showing date i.e

```
1/2/2012  5
             If (2/2/2012 is not there)
3/2/2012  9
```

I want to list all dates. i.e like this

```
1/2/2012  5
2/2/2012  0
3/2/2012  9
```

How to do that?

Comment: so you want to 'add' a date and then show a zero count if it's not there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filling in missing days for rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421526/filling-in-missing-days-for-rows)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a CTE to generate a list of dates, and `left join` on that:

```
; with  Dates as
        (
        select  cast('2012-01-01' as date) as dt
        union all 
        select  dateadd(day, 1, dt)
        from    Dates
        where   dateadd(day, 1, dt) < '2012-01-06'
        )
select  d.dt
,       count(yt.id)
from    Dates d
left join    
        YourTable yt
on      yt.Date = d.Dt
group by
        d.dt;
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb32e/1/0)

Comment: +1, beat me to it. Can also use master..spt_values. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48be5/2