# Select between dates

Tags: sql, select

I have a table tem_data with temperatures values and dates

```
create table tem_data (id int not null, value float, date datetime);
```

Only when temperature changed , the new value inserted. 
For instance

```
  t   date
  15 12.09.2013
  17 15.09.2013
  23 19 09.2013
```

And the second table is a days for report

```
create table rDays(rDay datetime);

   rDay

  12.09.2013
  13.09.2013
  14.09.2013
  16.09.2013
  17.09.2013
  18.09.2013
  23.09.2013
```

All of it's rows should be in report, and as a result I want to have all days from rDays with it's temperature value.

```
       date              t
      12.09.2013       15
      13.09.2013       15
      14.09.2013       15
      16.09.2013       17
      17.09.2013       17 
      18.09.2013       17
      23.09.2013       19


select rDay,t from tem_data, rDays where ... ? , only ansi sql
```

Comment: Instead of trying to select rows in SQL that are not really there... you could simply create the missing data points in the application that displays the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Note that your upper bound is a `>` and not `>=`. If you really want `BETWEEN`, you have to subtract one from the end date, which I consider as unnecessary since it would not be displayed.

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT date as start_date
     , coalesce(lead(date) over (order by date)
              , convert(datetime, '12/31/9999')) as end_date
     , value
  FROM tem_data
)
SELECT rDays.rDay
     , value
  FROM rDays
 INNER JOIN t
    ON t.start_date <= rDay
   AND t.end_date > rDay
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server.

Please check the following SQL Fiddle for a working example.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d306/1

The answer is based on a earlier StackOverflow question on the same lines.

[Filling in missing days for rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421526/filling-in-missing-days-for-rows)

```
with dates (start_date, end_date) as
(select  min(tem_date), max(tem_date)
 from    tem_data t
 union all
 select  dateadd(d, 1, start_date), end_date
 from    dates d
 where   start_date < end_date
)
select start_date, q.tem_value
from dates d
cross apply (select top 1 tem_value
             from tem_data t
             where t.tem_date <= d.start_date
             order by t.tem_date desc
             ) q
option (maxrecursion 0)
```